# Prove: If $S =\{v_1 , v_2,v_3\}$ is a linearly independent set, then $\{v_1, v_2\}$ is linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove: If 
$S= \{v_1, v_2 ,v_ 3\}$ is a linearly independent set, then 
$\{v_1, v_2\}$ is 
 linearly independent.

Comment: $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are linealy independent, this means that $a_1v_1+a_2v_2+a3v_3=0$ means $a_1,a_2,a_3=0$. So now, suppose $b_1v_1+b_2v_2=0$ and W.L.O.G $b_1 \neq0$, then $b_!v_1+b_2v_2+0v_3=0$ but $b_1 \neq0$ which contradict the fact that $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are linearly independent.

Comment: [Here's what I see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZznAi.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Any subset of a linearly independent set is linearly independent.  If not, let $a_1,a_2$ not both zero, be such that $a_1v_1+a_2v_2=0$.  Then set $a_3=0$.  Now $a_1v_1+a_2v_2+a_3v_3=0$, is a nontrivial linear combination of $v_1,v_2,v_3$ equal to zero, a contradiction.